# Program to find pairs in array that XOR to a given value

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, xor

I am given an array and a value x.

Input example:

```
2 3
1 2
```

Where n (length of array) = 2, the value x = 3, and the next line (1, 2) contains the values in the array. I have to find the pairs of indices i, j so that a[i] XOR a[j] = x.

What I have implemented:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

   int n = sc.nextInt();
   int x = sc.nextInt();

   int[] arr = new int[n];

   HashSet<Integer> hash = new HashSet<Integer>();

   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
     hash.add(arr[i]);
   }

   int count = 0;

   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     if (hash.contains(arr[i]^x)) {
       count++;
     }
   }

   System.out.println(count/2);
  }

}
```

I have the divided the result by two because we only want to count a given pair once (only count [1, 2] not [1, 2] and [2, 1]).

I pass the given test above where the output is `1`, and this supplementary one where the output is `2`.

```
6 1
5 1 2 3 4 1
```

However I seem to fail some extra ones which I cannot see.

Comment: When you say you have to find the pairs of indicies, shouldn't the program display these indicies, or is it just meant to count how many there are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you check "contains", but for duplicate values this only returns a single occurrence. By using a set you throw duplicates away. Instead you should have a HashMap with number of occurrences:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> hash = new HashMap<>();

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
    if (!hash.containsKey(arr[i])) {
        hash.put(arr[i], 0)
    }
    hash.put(arr[i], hash.get(arr[i]) + 1);
}

int count = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (hash.containsKey(arr[i]^x)) {
        count += hash.get(arr[i]^x);
    }
}
```

Comment: And keep the System.out.println(count/2) ?

Comment: Yes, because you said you want to count combinations instead of permutations

Comment: Just a thought, this might not work as expected if `x = 0`. In this case it would find `n/2` extra solutions because it will combine each number with itself. If `i` and `j` may be identical then this is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic of dividing the `count` by `2` as the final answer, is not correct. 
Replace your logic by the following:

```
HashSet<Integer> hash = new HashSet<Integer>();

   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
   }

   int count = 0;

   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     if (hash.contains(arr[i]^x)) {
       count++;
     }
     hash.add(arr[i]);
   }

   System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: Hi. I think what you noticed was correct and I just corrected it, but it seems I am still failing some test cases... Any other ideas?

Comment: look at @fafl 's  answer. I think it might help you

Answer (score 0):

Your program doesn't handle duplicate numbers properly. It deals with `5 1 2 3 4 1` okay because `1` isn't part of the solution. What if it is?

Let's say number `a[i] ^ a[j]` is a solution as is `a[i] ^ a[k]`. In other words, `a[j] == a[k]`. The line `hash.contains(arr[i]^x)` will only count `a[i]` once.

You can solve this by having nested `for` loops.

```
for (int i = ...) {
  for (int j = ...) {
    if (a[i] ^ a[j] == x) {
      count++;
    }
  }
}
```

This approach lets you get rid of the `hash` set. And if you're clever enough filling out the `...` parts you can avoid double counting the pairs and won't have to divide `count` by 2.

Comment: I think the idea of the hash was to solve this in O(n) instead of O(n^2)

Comment: Indeed, your solution would be correct but the whole point of using the hash was to reduce the algorithm to O(n).